# How to make a popup menu added to a JtextField to be invisible when the JTextField's focus is lost?

Tags: java, swing

I have added to a JTextField a JPopupMenu. Unfortunatelly, when i change the focus from JTextField, or when i "minimize" the window, the JPopupMenu still is visible.
I need to make it invisible if JTextField is loosing the focus.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register a [focus listener](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/FocusListener.html) with the text field. The listener's focusLost() method should hide the menu.